# How do I convert intmax_t containing microseconds amount to an appropiate std::chrono::duration variable?

Tags: c++11, std, c++-chrono

How do I convert `intmax_t` containing microseconds amount to an appropriate `std::chrono::duration` variable?
More specifically,

```
...

intmax_t myUsInterval = 10000000LL; /* my desirable interval is 10s in us units */

std::chrono::duration<std::intmax_t, std::micro> timeout; /* I want to get timeout variable to use it in std::chrono library */

/* How can I: timeout <- myUsInterval ???????? */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::chrono::microseconds timeout{myUsInterval};
```

Or if you really want the `intmax_t` rep (which is not needed in this example):

```
std::chrono::duration<std::intmax_t, std::micro> timeout{myUsInterval};
```

For a video tutorial of `<chrono>`, see: [CppCon 2016: Howard Hinnant “A ＜chrono＞ Tutorial" on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M)